# Copying all files inside the directory but the main is not copying

Tags: java, directory, swt

I have this code that copies all files inside the directory and sub-directories and it works fine but my problem is it is not copying the main folder where the files are stored. (ex. D:\try\tryfolder) in this example all files inside the tryfolder will be copied but not the tryfolder itself.

this is my code:

```
public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
            throws IOException{
//      File nextDirectory = new File(src, dest.getName());
        if(src.isDirectory()){
            if (!dest.exists())
            {
                dest.mkdir();
                text1.append("Directory created : " + dest + "\n");
            }
                    final String files[] = src.list();
                    for (String file : files)
                    {
                        File srcFile = new File(src, file);
                        File destFile = new File(dest, file);

                        //Recursive function call
                        copyFolder(srcFile, destFile);
                    }


        }
        else{
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
            text1.append("");
            Files.copy(src.toPath(), dest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            text1.append(text + " Copying " + src.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2 questions:
Where is it copying the files to, if it isn't creating the destination directory?
Is the "Directory created : " output in your code being rendered?

Comment: basically i have a directory dialog and put it on the `textbox` and yes if destination can't find. @AndrewMcGuinness